# Why do some RxJS 6 operators take predicates and projections / selectors?

Tags: rxjs

This is a question about the design of RxJS 6. Consider two operators as examples.

1. [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/combineLatest) takes as an optional parameter a *projection* or *selector* (called by different names in different areas of the documentation), i.e. a function that maps from the values of the input observables to a type that will be the value type of the returned observable.

   Presumably, `combineLatest([as, bs], f)` is the same as `combineLatest([as, bs]).pipe(map(f))`.
2. [`last`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/last) takes as an (optional) parameter a *predicate* that can be used to filter values from the source observable.

   Presumably, `source.pipe(last(p))` is the same as `source.pipe(filter(p), last())`. ^1

Given these equivalencies, why take additional selectors and projections at all? What is the benefit of violating the single responsibility principle in this way?

^1: Or nearly so; `last` passes the source observable to the predicate, but `filter` does not. Most predicates will not need that parameter, and the few who do can use some pipe gymnastics:

```
source.pipe(src => {
  const p2 = (value, index) => p(value, index, src)
  return filter(p2)(src)
})
```

Comment: now that I have answered your question, I also need to remind you that SO tries to stay away from questions whose answers are opinion-based for obvious reasons. It would not be surprising that your question soon get closed. RXjs has a [gitter forum](https://gitter.im/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS) where you can ask this kind of question freely. It can additionally be more welcoming than here.

Comment: Result selectors are deprecated in RxJS 6 already and will be removed in RxJS 7. The reason is described here https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#result-selectors-removed-or-deprecated

Answer (score 1):

There are people around who are/were involved in the Rxjs V6 API design. They may complement this answer.

My guess here is that `combineLatest([as, bs], f)` has performance advantages over `combineLatest([as, bs]).pipe(map(f))`. That was at least the rationale in Rxjs v4. It may continue to be so in the v6. `pipe` introduces a level of indirection that you do not have by directly passing the predicate which may result in lower performance. Similarly, `obs.pipe(f,g)` should be less performant than `obs.pipe(x => g(f(x)))`. As usual when it comes to performance, measuring is everything, and this would be the kind of microoptimization that you want to do after having done everything else.